# How to implement Isotope JS multiple filter (Checkbox & Search) with Paginations - WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-isotope

How to implement Isotope JS multiple filters (Checkbox & Search) with Paginations in WordPress.

I have used multiple isotope filters in my WordPress post collection. I used the button & search filter but when I tried to implement pagination with this than the filter not works.

**Here is My JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    var buttonFilters = {};
    var buttonFilter;
    var qsRegex;

    var $grid = $('.blog-list').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.blog-item',
        filter: function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
            var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
            return searchResult && buttonResult;
        },
    });


    var currentPage = 1;
    var itemsPerPageDefault = 10;
    var itemSelector = '.blog-item'; 
    
    var currentFilter = '*';
    var filterAtribute = 'data-filter';
    var pageAtribute = 'data-page';
    var pagerClass = 'isotope-pager';
    var responsiveIsotope = [
        [480, 3],
        [720, 3]
    ];

    function changeFilter(selector) {
        $grid.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
    }

    function goToPage(n) {
        currentPage = n;

        var selector = itemSelector;
            selector += ( currentFilter != '*' ) ? '['+filterAtribute+'="'+currentFilter+'"]' : '';
            selector += '['+pageAtribute+'="'+currentPage+'"]';

        changeFilter(selector);
    }

    function defineItemsPerPage() {
        var pages = itemsPerPageDefault;

        for( var i = 0; i < responsiveIsotope.length; i++ ) {
            if( $(window).width() <= responsiveIsotope[i][0] ) {
                pages = responsiveIsotope[i][1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return pages;
    }

    var itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
    
    function setPagination() {
        var SettingsPagesOnItems = function(){
            var itemsLength = $grid.children(itemSelector).length;
            var pages = Math.ceil(itemsLength / itemsPerPage);
            var item = 1;
            var page = 1;
            var selector = itemSelector;
                selector += ( currentFilter != '*' ) ? '['+filterAtribute+'="'+currentFilter+'"]' : '';
            
            $grid.children(selector).each(function(){
                if( item > itemsPerPage ) {
                    page++;
                    item = 1;
                }
                $(this).attr(pageAtribute, page);
                item++;
            });
            currentNumberPages = page;
        }();

        var CreatePagers = function() {
            var $isotopePager = ( $('.'+pagerClass).length == 0 ) ? $('<div class="'+pagerClass+'"></div>') : $('.'+pagerClass);
            $isotopePager.html('');
            for( var i = 0; i < currentNumberPages; i++ ) {
                var $pager = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pager" '+pageAtribute+'="'+(i+1)+'"></a>');
                    $pager.html(i+1);   
                    $pager.click(function(){
                        var page = $(this).eq(0).attr(pageAtribute);
                        goToPage(page);
                    });
                $pager.appendTo($isotopePager);
            }
            $grid.after($isotopePager);
        }();
    }

    setPagination();
    goToPage(1);

    $('.filters').on( 'click', '.button', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.button-group');
        var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
        buttonFilters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
        buttonFilter = concatValues( buttonFilters );
        $grid.isotope();
    });
    
    var $quicksearch = $('.blogsearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
        qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
        $grid.isotope();
        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);
    }));

    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
        $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
            setPagination();
            goToPage(1);
            $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
        });
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);
    });


    function concatValues( obj ) {
        var value = '';
        for ( var prop in obj ) {
            value += obj[ prop ];
        }
        return value;
    }

    function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
        var timeout;
        threshold = threshold || 100;
        return function debounced() {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
            var args = arguments;
            var _this = this;
            function delayed() {
            fn.apply( _this, args );
            }
            timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
        };
    }

});
```

How to make multiple isotop filters with pagination.

Comment: What you got there in Isotope is client-side filtering, you can't just combine that with server-side pagination easily. You will either need to move the pagination to the client side as well (load all data upfront, insert it into the document, and then _hide_ the elements that are not "on" your current page number), or do the filtering on the server side as well.

Comment: hi, have you found the solution to this problem ?